# Multiple Ring Buffer performance issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, buffer, performance, arcgis-pro

I just computed multiple ring buffers for a point in EPSG 4326 with a 100m interval for a maximum distance of 1000m. I was observing a calculation time of approximately:

- 50s within ArcMap;
- 4min in ArcGIS Pro; and
- 40s as a processing service on ArcGIS Server 10.5.1.

I would like to see the same performance in ArcGIS Pro as well as ArcMAp because I am shipping a toolbox with this arcpy command:

```py
def createDistances(incr,maximum):
    #as we have the raster now, we will need a multiple ring buffer:
    distances = []
    for dist in range(incr,maximum+1,incr):
        distances.append(str(dist))
        distancesString = ";".join(distances)
    return distancesString

distancesString = createDistances(100,1000)
arcpy.analysis.MultipleRingBuffer("Your single point feature", r"your ring buffer name", distancesString, "Meters", "distance", "ALL", "FULL")
```

Are there ways to increase calculation times in ArcGIS Pro?

I am running this on a X270 with this spec:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2904 MHz, 2 Cores, 4 logical processors
16Gb Ram, SSD

no dedicated GPU.

Answer (score 2):

There is no blanket way to "increase calculation times in ArcGIS Pro". This is likely a bug in the Multiple Ring Buffer tool. I work on the Esri development team, and we are making considerable performance enhancements to this tool in the 2.2 release. If you attach your test data in a zip or web location I can give it a shot.

Comment: I was using a single point feature from a fgdb. No attributes, no domains or anything!